# CSS: pointer-events:none deshabilita input text y botones

Tags: html, css, hover

En el sitio tengo varias tablas. A la mayoría le tengo aplicada la regla de CSS:

```
tr:hover { background-color: #D0D0D0 !important; }
```

para resaltar la línea y facilitar la lectura. En algunas tablas, aplico la regla:

```
.noHover { pointer-events: none; }
```

para no resaltar, por ejemplo, en tablas de resumen.

En esas tablas de resumen, a veces tengo algún `input="text"` y algún botón que quedan inhabilitados cuando le aplico la regla `.noHover`.
He leído al respecto pero no entiendo bien qué pasa ni por qué.

Ahora, cuando simulo esas tablas con `div`s, todo funciona bien.

Graceas!

Answer (score 1):

`pointer-events: none` se utiliza para evitar que se pueda interactuar con los elementos, o sea que se le impide recibir eventos de puntero (como hover, click, etc.) Simplemente tienes que añadir el `pointer-events: auto;` donde quieras que haya interactividad. Algo así:

```css
input,
button {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: Bien, `auto` mantiene los controles activos aunque cuando hago `hover` sobre los controles, le cambia el fondo a la línea (como `tr:hover` en mi caso)